# jQuery - multiple statements inside a click function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to achieve 2 things in order:

1. delete the selected radio button
2. after the deletion, select the first radio button of the remaining radio buttons.

I wrote following code but I cannot get the first radio button checked after deletion if I select any radio button other than the first of the remaining (I'm using jQuery 3.1.1 with Visual Studio):

```
$(':button').click(function (e) {
    $(':radio:checked').closest('tr').remove();
    $(':radio').first().attr("checked", true);
});
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I recreated your situation on a JSFiddle here and see no bugs with your code. I can't reproduce the problem. Can you make a JSFiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/8kfm87gb/

Comment: Add your HTML to the question as well

Answer (score 2):

Use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method for updating the element property.

```
$(':button').click(function (e) {
   $(':radio:checked').closest('tr').remove();
   $(':radio').first().prop("checked", true);
});
```

Comment: `attr()` and `prop()` have identical behavior in this case (at least in the version of jQuery he's using).

Comment: It worked perfectly. prop definitely seems better than attr. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how do I award points to people who respond successfully?